Azure Logic App External HTTP Authentication
Can anyone point me to a good reference for using a .cer certificate to authenticate to an external system for an HTTP action? I've seen info on converting to a .pfx and putting that value in the action but I was wondering if I can just upload the cert (.cer) to the logic app and somehow reference the thumbprint.

Http action allows us using pfx files and AFAIK, .cer  files does not contain the private key which is needed in authentication process  in Logic apps due to which  you need to convert it into .pfx and then you can use directly in action or upload that .pfx certificate to azure keyvault and later use it in Logic app using secret identifier. Then you can use in http action:

